# Unable to upload iOS app to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm building an iOS 14 app and I'm unable to upload it to App Store Connect.

When I try to upload via Xcode (both 12 and 12.1), I get this error and I can't find any relevant help for this specific error.

[image]

I tried the following

1. restarting Xcode
2. log out and log in again in Xcode
3. try to upload via Transporter app as mentioned in [Apple help page](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036).

The first two options didn't work. The Transporter app is showing the following error.

[image]

But in the Apple accounts page, it is clearly mentioned App Specific password is only for services not provided by Apple.

[image]

But I tried anyways and when I type an App Specific Password into Xcode or Transporter, it shows incorrect password.

I'm struck now, being unable to upload my app to App Store Connect.

Answer (score 1):

I had this in my mind from the beginning. But seriously hoped this will not be the case.

Restarting my Mac solved the issue.